# Obtain current user url when user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Here's the deal: An user goes to a page of my website which has tabs and founds out an error on the content of the tab, then he sees below the button "Report" (which is all outside the tabs). When he clicks this button, the current url in which the user is will get send by email.

The initial basement question of all this plan is: ¿How do i get the current url page of the user when the user clicks the button "Report"?

Comment: you can use like this in javascript. document.write(document.URL);

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript try

`window.location.href`

Comment: Make your answer complete. Explain what you want to say. This is not an answer to that question.

Comment: why isn't it the answer? it actually does what they want.

Comment: Of course your answer is not wrong, but the question is `How do i get the current url page of the user when the user clicks the button "Report"?`. It's better to include more details in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Location.href`  That will give you the current URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both `window.location.href` and `document.URL` to get the URL of the current page.

The difference between them is - `window.location.href` is settable, and `document.URL` is not.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite get this working with JSfiddle because of trying to navigate to a new page within their frames. But this is a self contained html example that you should be able to paste into your page and have working. It opens the client's default email program, prepopulating the body with the current URL.

```
    <style>
        div#reportButton {
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #dd7777;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id='reportButton'>Report a problem</div>
    <script>
        var button = document.getElementById("reportButton");
        button.onclick = function(){
            var currentURL = window.location.href;
            window.location.href="mailto:webmaster@example.com?subject=Bug+report&body=Problem+with+URL+" + currentURL;
        }
    </script>
```